# can be nullable and must be unique validation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'id_num' => 'required | unique:users', //this should be nullable not required with unique.
]);
```

Is it possible to nullable + unique at a time? then what will be the procedures?

Comment: `'id_num' => 'unique:users'` this can be nullable, if it has valure then need to be unique

Comment: ok thanks...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the required from the validator.

**Is it possible to nullable + unique at a time?**

Yes

**then what will be the procedures?**

You don't need a procedure, declare the field as unique in the table migration.

```php
$table->unique('id_num')->nullable();
```

then your validator must look like:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'id_num' => 'unique:users', //this is nullable since it is not required, but it checks for unique
]);
```

Comment: @Daniela unique in migration is not enough. If you input duplicate data then you will get error from SQL. You need to handle it with validation

Comment: You're right. But it's not necessary to define a special or aditional procedure to define a field as unique and nullable ouside from the things already done in the question. The validator in the question already validates the unique.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

`id_num` can be nullable, if it has value then need to be unique :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'id_num' => 'unique:users',
]);
```

Just remove the `required`